# Android Update specific Json

Tags: android, json

Lets say i have 2 different JSON's in my database how i can update/add more values to json with name user123 without affecting region and name values.

```
{
"region": "EU",
"Name": "User12345",
}

{
"region": "EU2",
"Name": "User123",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON in database table is just like a plain string. you need to fetch it.. modify it.. and then insert it again to database table.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we skip all parsing method which is easy to find on the internet. After parsing your desired json u can add it like this

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                            try {                                   
                                jsonDoc.put("key", value);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```